# Error when compiling using gmp

Tags: c, compiler-errors, gmp

I got this error when trying to compile my code which uses GMP. Is there any way i can solve this? Im using the visual studio 2010 command prompt to compile and this is the command i used:

> cl testing.c gmp.lib

```
int main(void)
{
    mpz_t a,b;
    mpz_init(b);
    mpz_init(a);
    gmp_randstate_t rstate; // the problem arises when declaring this
}

testing.c
testing.c(9) : error C2275: 'gmp_randstate_t' : illegal use of this type as an e
xpression
        c:\cygwin\home\administrator\ss\gmp.h(252) : see declaration of 'gmp_ran
dstate_t'
testing.c(9) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'state'

testing.c(9) : error C2065: 'state' : undeclared identifier
testing.c(11) : error C2065: 'state' : undeclared identifier
testing.c(11) : warning C4047: 'function' : '__gmp_randstate_struct *' differs i
n levels of indirection from 'int'
testing.c(11) : warning C4024: '__gmp_randinit_default' : different types for fo
rmal and actual parameter 1
testing.c(13) : error C2065: 'state' : undeclared identifier
testing.c(13) : warning C4047: 'function' : '__gmp_randstate_struct *' differs i
n levels of indirection from 'int'
testing.c(13) : warning C4024: '__gmpz_urandomb' : different types for formal an
d actual parameter 2
testing.c(14) : error C2065: 'state' : undeclared identifier
testing.c(14) : warning C4047: 'function' : '__gmp_randstate_struct *' differs i
n levels of indirection from 'int'
testing.c(14) : warning C4024: '__gmpz_urandomb' : different types for formal an
d actual parameter 2
```

Comment: you should include your actual code.

Comment: Why you using headers under cygwin to compile with VC++?

Comment: have added the source code, it was placed in the cygwin folder as temporary. It has no affect on the code even then i moved it out of the cygwin folder

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to initialize it.

"Such a variable must be
initialized by a call to one of the gmp_randinit functions, and can be seeded with one of the
gmp_randseed functions." - manual pg 65.